# Is there's a tool for managing source.list?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get

Is there's any tool for managing `/etc/apt/source.list`? I've had already couple of variants when I need it so bad, for example when using `fabric` or `chef` or when using `veewee` for building boxes of `Vagrant`.

Every time using sed, and putting my own mirrors doesn't look really productive. That's why I'm asking maybe anybody knows a tool to manage source.list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git? But you should be separating your lists.

Put the mirrors in separate files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

This way if you need all you fabric mirrors, copy `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fabric.list`.

This will be changeable by something like puppet or saltstack. If you then `/etc/apt/preference` correctly, when fabric mirrors are present then they will be used in preference to other mirrors (where there is a conflict of package versions and dependencies).

Comment: separating source.list not an option when you want to add contrib/non-free to main :) but yeah for other repos it's perfect solution

Comment: In one 
`deb http://debrepo.org/debian main`
in other
`deb http://debrepo.org/debian contrib non-free`
works fine.